# What if we console a variable just before declare it

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

What is the difference between the following two cases:

**CASE 1:**

```
console.log(c); //console : undefined
var c;
```

**CASE 2:**

```
console.log(c); //console : Uncaught ReferenceError: c is not defined
```

Why in Case 1 it console undefined? as it was declare after `console.log()`. At that time variable c is also **not defined** than why program console **undefined**

Comment: it has to do with *hoisting* - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting - i,e technically, your first code snippet is equivalent to .. `var c; console.log(c);` -because variable declarations are hoisted to the top of the function scope

Comment: interestingly the output is identical with `console.log(c); var c = 'hello, world';` ... because then the code is equivalent to `var c; console.log(c); c = 'hello, world';` - which demonstrates "hoisting" a little more clearly

Comment: [What went wrong?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined)
There is a non-existent variable referenced somewhere. This variable needs to be declared, or you need make sure it is available in your current script or scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Please check docs for `var` statement in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

> variable declarations (and declarations in general) are processed before any code is executed, declaring a variable anywhere in the code is equivalent to declaring it at the top. This also means that a variable can appear to be used before it's declared. This behavior is called "hoisting", as it appears that the variable declaration is moved to the top of the function or global code.

So, in first example variable has been declared, but was not defined (even with `var c = 1;` before that row it would be not defined). In the second example, it was not declared at all.